# Raspberry pi camera on jetson nano wont work

Tags: javascript, nvidia-jetson-nano, picamera

Im using raspberry pi camera v2 on jetson nano. It works fine using gstreamer with python but trying to run it through javascrip wont work.

This is some of my approaches:

**APPROACH 1:**

With navigator:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
    </div>
    <!--<script type="module" src="./picam.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                })
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

With response:

> (index):1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Requested device not
> found

**APPROACH 2:**

Using:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pi-camera-connect

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
    </div>
    <script>
        const { StreamCamera, Codec } = require("pi-camera-connect");
        const streamCamera = new StreamCamera({
            codec: Codec.H264
        });
        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("video-stream.h264");
        const videoStream = streamCamera.createStream();
        videoStream.pipe(writeStream);
        streamCamera.startCapture().then(() => {
            setTimeout(() => streamCamera.stopCapture(), 5000);
        }); </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

**APPROACH 3:**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
    </div>
    <script type="module">
        import { StreamCamera, Codec } from "pi-camera-connect";
        import * as fs from "fs";

        // Capture 5 seconds of H264 video and save to disk
        const runApp = async () => {
            const streamCamera = new StreamCamera({
                codec: Codec.H264
            });

            const videoStream = streamCamera.createStream();
            const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("video-stream.h264");
            videoStream.pipe(writeStream);

            await streamCamera.startCapture();
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 5000));
            await streamCamera.stopCapture();
        };

        runApp();
    </script>
</body>
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
> "pi-camera-connect".

Anyone successfully run raspberry pi camera on jetson nano with javascript?

This python approach works fine though:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
dispW=640
dispH=480
flip=2
camSet='nvarguscamerasrc !  video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=3264, height=2464, format=NV12, framerate=21/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method='+str(flip)+' ! video/x-raw, width='+str(dispW)+', height='+str(dispH)+', format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink'
cam= cv2.VideoCapture(camSet)

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('nanoCam',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to run node.js code in a browser. That won't work, since nodejs is a server application. `require` not found shows that you are running in an environment that doesn't contain nodejs. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to a) connect to a jetson on the network through a webserver and see pi camera images? or b) See a camera feed from the browser that is running on the jetson?

Comment: Im running the code with live-server. No, I am simply trying to use raspberry pi camera instead of ordinary webcam in a video-element